# syncing data with server

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to sync data from my application onto the server. I'm very
new to this kind of work.
For this i wrote a small web service in php,

Now, i'm not able to figure out how to call this web service and how
to send the 2 variable values to the insertData function from the app
using xCode.

Any kind of help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
NR

Answer (score 1):

I would not sync data via php or http in general if i don't have to. I'd use simple things like [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy), [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) or, if the data relates to my application some version control, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/).

However, doing this via php could look something like this:

```
<!-- server side, lets say the url is http://example.org/sync.php -->
<?php 
    insert_stuff($_GET["username"], $_GET["password"]); 
    echo "Inserted.\n";
?>
```

Locally, i'd use [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL):

```
$ curl "http://example.org/sync.php?username=root&password=root"
Inserted.
```

...